# Using MongoChef with mongodb in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, studio3t

I want to use MongoChef to manage MongoDB that I have running as docker container, but I cannot find how I use IntelliShell in MongoChef...

It asks from me the path to mongo executable, but I do not have it, because I didn't install mongodb locally, I only have a running container.

How do I make MongoChef to work with MongoDB in container?

** I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 if it matters.

Thanks!